# How to put sent and receive css in signalr sent and received message in blazor?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-core, blazor

Here I have made simple blazor chat application with database using SignalR.
Now, my problem is that I have have css for sent and received message but I don't know any logic to put those css in my sent and received messages.
Help with my code will be great.
Below is my code

```
    public string MsgBody { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public Message chatmsg { get; set; } = new Message();
    public bool isChatting = false;
    public string errorMsg;
    public List<Message> messages = new List<Message>();
    public HubConnection hubConnection;
    [Inject]
    public NavigationManager NavigationManager { get; set; }
    [Inject]
    public MainService mainService { get; set; }
    public async Task Chat()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(UserName))
        {
            errorMsg = "Enter your name";
        }
        try
        {
            isChatting = true;
            messages.Clear();
            hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl(NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/chat")).Build();
            hubConnection.ServerTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
            hubConnection.On<string>("Reicever", BroadcastMessage);
            await hubConnection.StartAsync();

            messages = mainService.GetAllMessages();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            errorMsg = $"ERROR: Failed to start chat client: {e.Message}";
            isChatting = false;
        }
    }
    private void BroadcastMessage(string name)
    {
        messages = mainService.GetAllMessages();
        StateHasChanged();
    }
    public async Task SendAsync()
    {
        chatmsg.UsrName = UserName;
        chatmsg.MessageBody = MsgBody;
        mainService.SaveMessage(chatmsg);
        await hubConnection.SendAsync("SendMessage");
        MsgBody = string.Empty;
        chatmsg = new Message();
    }
    public async Task DisconnectAsync()
    {
        if (isChatting)
        {
            await hubConnection.StopAsync();
            await hubConnection.DisposeAsync();

            hubConnection = null;
            isChatting = false;
        }
    }
```

Below is my view

```
@if (!isChatting)
{
    <div class="col-lg-5">
        <p>Enter your name to start chatting:</p>

    <div class="input-group  my-3">
        <input @bind="UserName" type="text" class="form-control my-input">
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" @onclick="@Chat"><span class="oi oi-chat" aria-hidden="true"></span> Chat!</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    if (errorMsg != null)
    {
       <div class="col-lg-5">
          <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-danger">@errorMsg</small>
       </div>
    }
}
else
{
<div class="alert alert-secondary mt-4" role="alert">
    <span class="oi oi-person mr-2" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span>you are connected as <b>@UserName</b></span>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning ml-md-auto" @onclick="@DisconnectAsync">disconnect</button>
</div>
<div id="scrollbox">
    @foreach (var item in messages)
    {
        <div> // message sent and receive css in this div
            <div class="user">@item.UsrName</div>
            <div class="msg">@item.MessageBody</div>
        </div>
    }
    <hr />
    <textarea class="input-lg" placeholder="enter your comment" @bind="MsgBody"></textarea>
    <button class="btn btn-default" @onclick="()=>SendAsync()">Send</button>
</div>
}
```

Below is  my css

```
.received, .sent {
position: relative;
font-family: arial;
font-size: 1.1em;
border-radius: 10px;
padding: 20px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.received:after, .sent:after {
    content: '';
    border: 20px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -30px;
}

.sent {
background: #03a9f4;
color: #fff;
margin-left: 10%;
top: 50%;
text-align: right;
}

.received {
background: #4CAF50;
color: #fff;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-right: 10%;
}

.sent:after {
border-left-color: #03a9f4;
border-right: 0;
right: -20px;
}

.received:after {
border-right-color: #4CAF50;
border-left: 0;
left: -20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much any html property can use a string variable:

```
<div class="msg @CSS">This is my text</div>
<button @onclick="UpdateClass">Change</button>

@code {
    string CSS = "normal";

    void UpdateClass()
    {
        CSS = "Receive";
    }
}
```

If you inspect the message div in the example above in Chrome dev tools, you will see that it very happily changes the class for you as soon as you click the button.

I recommend adding a new member, `string CssClass`, to your Message class, so you can set and use it very easily:

```
<div class="msg @item.CssClass">@item.MessageBody</div>
```